# Multisite Demo Data for New Site

Tags: multisite

Please help me, I want in my multisites if I have new register member  automatic have demo data, what should I do

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: so far I've been using plugins Demo Data Creator, but it was not the way I want, I already possessed essentially xml file ready for the demo when the user first create a new site. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not came across readymade file for multisite demo data on WordPress. But I had used this plugin in the past. Please check this to generate multisite demo data: https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-data-creator/

Comment: thanks your respone dude, but I have file xml and on plugin demo creator page, blog etc generate outomatic.